# MySQL INSERT SELECT - Duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do an INSERT SELECT query like this:

```
INSERT INTO `tableName` (SELECT * FROM `anotherTable`)
```

The problem is when it finds a duplicate value the whole thing will stop, really I just want it to continue and skip the duplicates.

I know I can do this via the cmd line by using the -f parameter to force it, but I want to do it with PHP. Is there a force or ignore errors option somewhere in the PHP mysql_* functions?

Comment: Have a look at this INSERT IGNORE -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE :

```
INSERT INTO `tableName` (SELECT * FROM `anotherTable`) ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE
```

Info here-> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [INSERT IGNORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `tableName` (SELECT * FROM `anotherTable`)
```